# How to make clicked tab and its contents active and others as inactive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My jsfiddle link was https://jsfiddle.net/1at91Lgo/,

The html that i have used,

```
<section class="ourscl" id="school">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="text-center">
        <h2 class="hdng"><span class="schools-title">Our Schools</span></h2>
        <h4 class="italic-line"> 100+ schools with world class education </h4>
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified navbar-default" style="color:white;margin-top:30px;margin-bottom:30px">
          <li class="active brdrlft tab-wid font-sz"><a href="#matric" data-toggle="pill">Matriculation Stream</a></li>
          <li class="brdrlft tab-wid font-sz"><a href="#cbse" data-toggle="pill">CBSE Stream</a></li>
          <li class="brdrlft tab-wid font-sz"><a href="#stateboard" data-toggle="pill" >State Board</a></li>
          <li class="tab-wid font-sz"><a href="#college" data-toggle="pill" >B.Ed College</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content" style="margin-top:30px;margin-bottom:30px">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="brdrlt" id="matric">
                <a target="_blank" href="http://sowthuraiyur.edu.in/">
                  <h4>Sowdambikaa Boys MHSS</h4>
                  <p>Thuraiyur - Trichy</p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="brdrlt" id="matric">
                <a target="_blank" href="http://sowthottiyam.edu.in/">
                  <h4>Sowdaambikaa MHSS</h4>
                  <p>Thottiyam - Trichy</p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="brdrlt" id="matric">
                <a target="_blank" href="http://sowshivani.edu.in/">
                  <h4>Sowdambikaa MHSS</h4>
                  <p>T.Pettai - Trichy</p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="brdrlt" id="matric">
                <a target="_blank" href="http://cmhss.edu.in/">
                  <h4>Chellammal Boys MHSS</h4>
                  <p>Thiruverumbur - Trichy</p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="brdrlt" id="matric">
                <a target="_blank" href="http://chelammal.edu.in/">
                  <h4>Chelammal MHSS</h4>
                  <p>Crawford - Trichy</p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="brdrlt" id="matric">
                <a target="_blank" href="http://akkv.sowdambikaa.edu.in/">
                  <h4>AKKV MHSS</h4>
                  <p>Annamalai Nagar - Trichy</p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="brdrlt" id="matric">
                <a target="_blank" href="http://sowthuraiyur.edu.in/">
                  <h4>Sowdambikaa Girls MHSS</h4>
                  <p>Thuraiyur - Trichy</p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="brdrlt" id="matric">
                <a target="_blank" href="">
                  <h4>Chellammal MHSS</h4>
                  <p>Nagamangalam - Trichy</p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="brdrlt" id="matric">
                <a target="_blank" href="">
                  <h4>Chellammal MHSS</h4>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="brdrlt" id="cbse">
                <a target="_blank" href="http://srmschool.edu.in/">
                  <h4>SRM Public</h4>
                  <p>Thuraiyur - Trichy</p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="brdrlt" id="stateboard">
                <a target="_blank" href="http://cmullai.sowdambikaa.edu.in/">
                  <h4>Mullai HSS</h4>
                  <p>Thottiyam - Trichy</p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="brdrlt" id="college">
                <a target="_blank" href="http://shivacollege.edu.in/">
                  <h4>Shiva College of Education</h4>
                  <p>Thathiengarpet - Trichy</p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>       <p>Viralimalai - Pudukottai</p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="brdrlt" id="matric">
                <a target="_blank" href="http://cmhss.edu.in/">
                  <h4>Chellammal Girls MHSS</h4>
                  <p>Thiruverumbur - Trichy</p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="brdrlt" id="cbse">
                <a target="_blank" href="http://cvcsmusiri.edu.in/">
                  <h4>Chelammal Vidhyaashram</h4>
                  <p>Musiri - Trichy</p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="brdrlt" id="cbse">
                <a target="_blank" href="http://cvcbse.edu.in/">
                  <h4>Chellammal Vidyalaya</h4>
                  <p>Thiruverumbur - Trichy</p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="brdrlt" id="cbse">
                <a target="_blank" href="http://srmschool.edu.in/">
                  <h4>SRM Public</h4>
                  <p>Thuraiyur - Trichy</p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="brdrlt" id="stateboard">
                <a target="_blank" href="http://cmullai.sowdambikaa.edu.in/">
                  <h4>Mullai HSS</h4>
                  <p>Thottiyam - Trichy</p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
              <div class="brdrlt" id="college">
                <a target="_blank" href="http://shivacollege.edu.in/">
                  <h4>Shiva College of Education</h4>
                  <p>Thathiengarpet - Trichy</p>
                </a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

And css was,

```
.ourscl .navbar-default{
    background-color:rgb(222, 35, 41) !important; /*rgb(144,21,14)!important;*/
}
.ourscl {
  background: #ffcb05;
}
.nav-pills li.active a{
    background-color: #FEC73D!important;
}
.nav-pills li a:focus{
    background-color:#FEC73D!important;
}
.nav-pills li a:hover{
    background-color: #FEC73D!important;
}
.nav-pills li a {
    color:#fff;
}
.nav-pills li a{
    border-radius:0px!important;
}
.hide-sec{
    display: none;
    text-align: left!important;
}
.nav-pills{
    display: block;
}
 .brdrlt{
     border-left:1px solid #FEC73D!important;
     text-align: left;
     padding-left: 10px;
   margin-bottom:20px;
 }
.tab-wid.active::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    /* top: 50%; */
    /* margin-top: -13px; */
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 13px solid transparent;
    border-left: 13px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid #FEC73D;
}
.schools-title {
  color: #fff;
  background: url(images/title_white.png) no-repeat bottom;
}
.italic-line {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.plus_image {
  background: url(images/plus-sign.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
.brdrlt h4 {
  color: #bc0101
}
.brdrlt p {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Here what i need was if i click on any menu on the tab(as in the fiddle), the selected menu and its content should get active, I have given id to all the contents that relates to the corresponding menu title..
The jquery script that i have tried was,

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$('.nav-pills li a').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');

     //removing active class from other selected/default tab
    $(".nav-pills li a .active").removeClass("active");

    //adding active class to current clicked tab
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
  </script>
```

I am sure that i was wrong in using this but i don't have a clear idea about achieving the result i want..
Here is the image of what actually i am in the need of..
[image]

Comment: you are adding .active to 'li'. But you are querying it as a child of anchor when removing the .active class  $(".nav-pills li a .active").removeClass("active"); >> $(".nav-pills li.active").removeClass("active"); ?

Comment: @karthick, but there is no change after making the corrections..

Comment: you have defined only one tab-content. what about the others?

Comment: I am very beginner here can you guide me what replacement should i make here?

Comment: @ManiRaj, you are assigning same `id` to multiple `div` which is not correct. Please assign a unique id to every element in html. If you really need to assign them same id then assign is as `data-id`. But `id` attribute should be unique.

Comment: @ManishYadav , If i click that title with ```href```, those href ```id's``` should get active so i kept like that.

Comment: @ManiRaj I noticed in your fiddle, you have multiple `id` with the same value, not a good idea.

Comment: @ManiRaj That's not how it works, you can only give an `id` to one element

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, Ya i can get your point will change it in my code can you give me a solution to achieve a result for this.

Comment: @ManishYadav got it, but it i need a suggestion from you to get my output as like i needed..

Comment: @ManiRaj "but give me a solution" sorry but that sound more like an order. If I was you I would strip your fiddle of all unwanted code, so it's easier to work with and then I would take it one step at the time,

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen, i apologise for it.. And sorry if it hurts you..

Comment: @ManiRaj, give a same `data-id` to all `div` in same category. Then create and apply a `class` (inactive)  to all divs, so that they are less visible. and then add active class to all `div` of clicked category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do not use multiple IDs . it's bad practice and it's messing up the whole site. When you try to link the `a` to `#` section it will only link to one of them...not to all.

anyway, i changed the href of a to simply `#` and added an attribute `data-target:example` that will link to each tab that has that class.

see snippet below or [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1at91Lgo/7/)

```js
$(".mtrcscl1").addClass("activetab")

$('.nav-pills li a').click(function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
    
 

     //removing active class from other selected/default tab
    $(".nav-pills li.active").removeClass("active");
     var target = $(this).attr("data-target") 
    //adding active class to current clicked tab
    $(this).parent().addClass("active");
  $(".activetab").removeClass("activetab")
  $("." + target).addClass("activetab")
  
});
```

```css
.ourscl .navbar-default{
 background-color:rgb(222, 35, 41) !important; /*rgb(144,21,14)!important;*/
}
.ourscl {
  background: #ffcb05;
}
.nav-pills li.active a{
 background-color: #FEC73D!important;
}
.nav-pills li a:focus{
 background-color:#FEC73D!important;
}
.nav-pills li a:hover{
 background-color: #FEC73D!important;
}
.nav-pills li a {
 color:#fff;
}
.nav-pills li a{
 border-radius:0px!important;
}
.hide-sec{
 display: none;
 text-align: left!important;
}
.nav-pills{
 display: block;
}
 .brdrlt{
  border-left:1px solid #FEC73D!important;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 10px;
   margin-bottom:20px;
  opacity:0.2;
  transition:0.3s;
 }
 .activetab .brdrlt {
  opacity:1;
 }
.tab-wid.active::after{
 content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    /* top: 50%; */
    /* margin-top: -13px; */
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 13px solid transparent;
    border-left: 13px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid red;
}
.schools-title {
  color: #fff;
  background: url(images/title_white.png) no-repeat bottom;
}
.italic-line {
  font-style: italic;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.plus_image {
  background: url(images/plus-sign.png);
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
.brdrlt h4 {
  color: #bc0101
}
.brdrlt p {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<section class="ourscl" id="school">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="text-center">
      <h2 class="hdng"><span class="schools-title">Our Schools</span></h2>
      <h4 class="italic-line"> 100+ schools with world class education </h4>
      <div class="plus_image"><img class="repeat_image"></div>
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified navbar-default" style="color:white;margin-top:30px;margin-bottom:30px">
        <li class="active brdrlft tab-wid font-sz"><a href="#" data-target="mtrcscl1" data-toggle="pill">Matriculation Stream</a></li>
        <li class="brdrlft tab-wid font-sz"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#" data-target="cbse">CBSE Stream</a></li>
        <li class="brdrlft tab-wid font-sz"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#" data-target="hgrscl">State Board</a></li>
        <li class="tab-wid font-sz"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#" data-target="clg">B.Ed College</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content" style="margin-top:30px;margin-bottom:30px">
        <!-- <div class="row tab-pane fade in active" id="mtrcscl1">
          <div class="rooms">
            <h2 class="hide-sec">Matriculation Stream</h2> -->
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-3" class="mtrcscl1">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://sowthuraiyur.edu.in/">
                    <h4>Sowdambikaa Boys MHSS</h4>
                    <p>Thuraiyur - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 mtrcscl1">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://sowthottiyam.edu.in/">
                    <h4>Sowdaambikaa MHSS</h4>
                    <p>Thottiyam - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 mtrcscl1">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://sowshivani.edu.in/">
                    <h4>Sowdambikaa MHSS</h4>
                    <p>T.Pettai - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 mtrcscl1">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://cmhss.edu.in/">
                    <h4>Chellammal Boys MHSS</h4>
                    <p>Thiruverumbur - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-3 mtrcscl1">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://chelammal.edu.in/">
                    <h4>Chelammal MHSS</h4>
                    <p>Crawford - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 mtrcscl1">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://akkv.sowdambikaa.edu.in/">
                    <h4>AKKV MHSS</h4>
                    <p>Annamalai Nagar - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 mtrcscl1">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://sowthuraiyur.edu.in/">
                    <h4>Sowdambikaa Girls MHSS</h4>
                    <p>Thuraiyur - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 mtrcscl1">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="">
                    <h4>Chellammal MHSS</h4>
                    <p>Nagamangalam - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-3 mtrcscl1">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="">
                    <h4>Chellammal MHSS</h4>
                    <p>Viralimalai - Pudukottai</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 mtrcscl1">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://cmhss.edu.in/">
                    <h4>Chellammal Girls MHSS</h4>
                    <p>Thiruverumbur - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 cbse">
                <!-- <div class="row tab-pane fade" id="cbse">
                <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                <div class="rooms col-sm-3">
                <h2 class="hide-sec">CBSE Stream</h2> -->
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://cvcsmusiri.edu.in/">
                    <h4>Chelammal Vidhyaashram</h4>
                    <p>Musiri - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm-3 cbse">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://cvcbse.edu.in/">
                    <h4>Chellammal Vidyalaya</h4>
                    <p>Thiruverumbur - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm-3 cbse">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://srmschool.edu.in/">
                    <h4>SRM Public</h4>
                    <p>Thuraiyur - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- <div class="row tab-pane fade" id="hgrscl">
              <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
              <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
              <div class="rooms col-sm-3">
              <h2 class="hide-sec">State Board</h2> -->
              <div class="col-sm-3 hgrscl">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://cmullai.sowdambikaa.edu.in/">
                    <h4>Mullai HSS</h4>
                    <p>Thottiyam - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <!-- <div class="row tab-pane fade" id="clg">
              <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
              <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
              <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
              <div class="rooms col-sm-3">
              <h2 class="hide-sec">B.Ed College</h2> -->
              <div class="col-sm-3 clg">
                <div class="brdrlt">
                  <a target="_blank" href="http://shivacollege.edu.in/">
                    <h4>Shiva College of Education</h4>
                    <p>Thathiengarpet - Trichy</p>
                  </a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, it looks fine, In addition to this what i needed is, the selected and active contents should come to the first row.. How to achieve it?

Comment: that's more complicated to do and your original question just wanted to achieve this ( active inactive tabs on click ) and so please accept my answer  . if you want more, you should first try to do it yourself and then post here what you have tried .

Comment: Definitely  i will accept your answer, but in addition to this i need this requirement which i didn't mention in question..So i asked you..